# Unresolved reference when using CardStackView Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val cardStackView = findViewById<CardStackView>(R.id.cardStack)
cardStackView.layoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager(this)
cardStackView.adapter = cardStackAdapter()
```

cardStackAdapter() gives an unresolved reference error, does anyone know what it should be instead

I'm using this github repo https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView